# Inserting nodes in a linked list in decreasing order - C

Tags: c, sorting, linked-list

I have to make a list that arrange the people in decreasing order of their number('no' for my program). I tryed to make it by modifying the `addNode` function but I got no result(peoples do not arrange by their number). This is my code:

Header code:

```
#ifndef __EX__
#define __EX__

typedef struct Person{
    char name[10];
    float no;
    struct Person *pNext;
} NODE, *pNODE, **ppNODE;

void addNode(ppNODE, pNODE);

void travers(pNODE, unsigned int*);


#endif
```

Functions folder:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <string.h>

#include "EX.h"

void addNode (ppNODE ppPrim, pNODE p){
    pNODE q = (pNODE)malloc(sizeof(NODE));
    assert(q!=NULL);

    printf("Add name: \n");
    scanf("%s", &q->name);


    printf("\nAdd no: ");
    scanf("%f", &q->no);


    if (p == NULL || q->no < p->no) {
        q->pNext = *ppPrim;
        *ppPrim = q;
    } else {
            q->pNext = p->pNext;
            p->pNext = q;

    }
    return;
}


void travers(pNODE pPrim, unsigned int *pLen){
    *pLen = 0;
    pNODE tmp = pPrim;


    while (tmp != NULL){
        puts (tmp->name);
        fprintf(stdout, " no %.2f\n", tmp->no);
        tmp = tmp->pNext;
        (*pLen)++;
    }

    return;
}
```

Main folder:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <string.h>

#include "EX.h"

int main(){
    unsigned int len;
    pNODE prim = NULL;
    int i;

    for (i=0; i<=1; i++){
        addNode(&prim, prim);
        addNode(&prim, prim->pNext);
    }

    travers(prim, &len);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Did you already execute the code step by step in the debugger? The for-loop in `main()` looks a little bit strange - I assume you did this while searching for the error...

Comment: All you need is to use Insertion Sort to treat you list as a priority queue. Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25437682/use-a-linked-list-to-implement-a-priority-queue)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you insert a new node to the list, you must traverse the list until you find a suitable place to insert it. Your code takes a second argument, which isn't really needed and causes confusion, and only looks at that.

The code to insert a code `q` at the end of a list that is defined by its `head` is:

```
Node *prev = NULL;
Node *p = *head;

while (p) {
    prev = p;
    p = p->pNext;
}

q->pNext = p;
if (prev == NULL) {
    *head = q;        
} else {
    prev->pNext = q;
}
```

You can get rid of keeping track of the previous node and the distinction between inserting at the head and inserting after that by traversing the list with a pointer to node pointer:

```
Node **p = &head;

while (*p && (*p)->no < q->no) {
    p = &(*p)->pNext;
}

q->pNext = *p;
*p = q;
```

In this concise code, `p` holds the address of the head at first and the address of the `pNext` pointer of the previous node. Both can be updated via `*p`.

You can now use this code to traverse only as far as the numbers associated with each node are smaller than the one of the node to insert. here's a complete program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <assert.h>

typedef struct Node Node;
void addNode(Node **p, const char *name, float no);
void travers(Node *pPrim, unsigned int *pLen);

struct Node {
    char name[10];
    float no;
    Node *pNext;
};

void addNode(Node **p, const char *name, float no)
{
    Node *q = malloc(sizeof(*q));
    assert(q != NULL);

    snprintf(q->name, sizeof(q->name), "%s", name);
    q->no = no;

    while (*p && (*p)->no < q->no) {
        p = &(*p)->pNext;
    }

    q->pNext = *p;
    *p = q;
}

void traverse(const Node *pPrim, unsigned int *pLen)
{
    *pLen = 0;

    while (pPrim != NULL) {
        fprintf(stdout, "%-12s%.2f\n", pPrim->name, pPrim->no);
        pPrim = pPrim->pNext;
        (*pLen)++;
    }
}

int main()
{
    unsigned int len;
    Node *prim = NULL;

    addNode(&prim, "Alice",   0.23);
    addNode(&prim, "Bob",     0.08);
    addNode(&prim, "Charlie", 0.64);
    addNode(&prim, "Dora",    0.82);

    traverse(prim, &len);
    printf("\n%u entries.\n", len);

    return 0;
}
```

Things to node:

- I've used `Node *` and `Node **` instead of the typedeffed `pNODE` and `ppNODE`. In my opinion using the C pointer syntax is clearer.
- You should separate taking user input from adding a node.
- In your code you shouldn't pass the address of the char array when scanning a string, just the char array. (It happens to work, but it isn't correct. The compiler should warn you about that.)